# What is a degenerate Convex hull?

Tags: linear-algebra, computational-geometry

In n-dimensional space, what are the conditions on n+2 vectors such that zeros belongs to the convex-hull formed by these vectors but does not belong to the convex hull formed by any n+1 vectors from the set?

Comment: Just an insight idea. Could it be, for each vector in the n+2 set, we can find its symmetric according to zeros?

Comment: This is not possible. In $\mathbb R^n$, if a point is in the convex hull of a set $P$, then it is in the convex hull of some $n+1$ points in $P$. This is [Carathéodory's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carath%C3%A9odory's_theorem_(convex_hull)).